# Tuple with `let` or `var`

Tags: swift, tuples

Let's say I have something like this:

```
func myFunc() -> (Any, Any)? {...}

func anotherFunc() {
    if var (a, b) = myFunc() {
        // a is mutated and accessed; b is accessed, but not mutated
        a = b
    }
}
```

I need `var` for the tuple as `a` is mutated, but Xcode complains that "`b`was never mutated, consider using `let`" - which is a somewhat reasonable argument, but I can't really define the tuple as `(var, let)`.

I guess I could use index to access the two elements instead of declaring them, circumventing this issue. But is there a better way?

Comment: If somebody wants to reproduce the problem: For some reason the warning is issued only if the if-statement is inside some function, not if it is top-level code.

Comment: that's interesting. Let me update my question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use pattern matching (i.e with `if case`), then you can use the [tuple binding pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID423), which allows you to annotate the mutability of the bindings separately:

```
if case (var a, let b)? = myFunc() {
    a = b
}
```

This also uses the [optional pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID520) `x?` in order to unwrap the result of `myFunc()`, given that we're now using pattern matching instead of optional binding.

Comment: Interesting, it turns out I *can* declare the tuple as `(var, let)`. Thanks @Hamish that works great

Comment: Happy to help @Stephenye :)

Comment: How would you do it if the return type was not optional?